# Тестирование android приложения

Tags: android, юнит-тесты

Подскажите фреймворки для unit и интеграционных тестов на андроид.

Comment: Ответ: unit-тесты и так далее. У вас очень обширный вопрос и в качестве ответа можно опубликовать здесь пару книг про тестирование android-приложений. Предлагаю вам конкретизировать вопрос.

Answer (score 4):

По хорошему вам бы погуглить. И изучить тему. А сюда идти уже с более конкретными вопросами.

Но раз уж вы тут, то вот вам набор фреймворков http://testdroid.com/tech/top-5-android-testing-frameworks-with-examples

Лично я бы вам посоветовал [robolectric](http://robolectric.org) и [espresso](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html).
Певый хорош тем, что не нужны никакие эмуляторы.
Второй позволяет запускать тесты на реальных устройствах.

Мне ближе robolectric, так как я с ним больше работал. Он позволяет покрыть всю бизнес логику unit тестами. И лучше обычного junit тем, что дает доступ к ресурсам андроида.